# Rails 4 app redirect_to not reloading webpage after post request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, post, actionmailer

I have a Rails 4 app where I have inside a controller an action that my routes.rb maps a route to as a post request.

```
post '/contact', :to => "page#contact_email"
```

Inside my page_controller.rb I have

```
  def contact_email
    mail = UserMailer.contact_email(params).deliver
    redirect_to root_url, notice: "Thank you for contacting us! We'll be in touch shortly"
   end
```

After posting to this URL with the form data necessary to send my email, the page sits still while I can see in the console it successfully sends the email, and does the redirect to '/'

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-10-21 19:42:34 -0700
Processing by ApplicationController#home as */*
Completed 200 OK in 792ms (Views: 780.6ms | ActiveRecord: 7.8ms)
```

Yet my webpage sits still and does nothing.

Any ideas?

Comment: `redirect_to` will reloading page, you should use ajax for submit your form.

Answer (score 2):

Since it seems you are doing an asynchronous post try replacing:

```
redirect_to root_url notice: "Thank you for contacting us! We'll be in touch shortly"
```

with

```
flash[:notice] = "Thank you for contacting us! We'll be in touch shortly"
render js: "window.location = '#{root_path}'"
```

Or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

`redirect_to root_url, notice: "Thank you for contacting us! We'll be in touch shortly"`

with

```
flash[:notice] = "Thank you for contacting us! We'll be in touch shortly"
redirect_to root_path
```

Comment: Sorry, I did not mean to edit your post. Misstook it for mine and thought I had made a copy paste misstake...